# Delta API returning empty array upon deletion of a list item

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-graph

I am implementing the ability to watch for deleted list items (E.g. a site page within SharePoint). My approach is the following:

1. I subscribe to change notifications for the list. Here's what my subscription looks like:

```json
        {
            "id": "45ae44db-bb7e-473c-9181-f2cdfd11b3f1",
            "resource": "sites/bartek.sharepoint.com,03c15e63-f29e-46b6-b2e7-642ed0687499,2d0352e9-2b90-498f-8083-a65428371102/lists/8dd4cccd-db7c-4e59-b916-65f5b59a8db7",
            "applicationId": "a6a88ddb-5938-470c-a11a-7aa310913052",
            "changeType": "updated",
            "clientState": null,
            "notificationUrl": "https://aef4-134-41-187-126.ngrok-free.app/callback/sharepoint/notifications",
            "notificationQueryOptions": null,
            "lifecycleNotificationUrl": null,
            "expirationDateTime": "2024-02-28T19:31:35Z",
            "creatorId": "70777dc5-0116-4fdd-9a0c-0128f4b4f979",
            "includeResourceData": null,
            "latestSupportedTlsVersion": "v1_2",
            "encryptionCertificate": null,
            "encryptionCertificateId": null,
            "notificationUrlAppId": null
        }
```

2. I receive the change notification for the list (updated as a page was deleted) and I query with the Delta API, using my previously known Delta URL with token (obtained via the `@odata.nextLink` as per documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/listitem-delta?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http)

When the page is modified, I receive a change notification and the Delta API shows the page in question. Great, I can update the page. However, when I delete the page I receive a Delta API response like so, with an empty array:

```json
{
  "url": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/bartek.sharepoint.com,43190b08-6a2a-4b9e-be35-d16751aab8da,56c688c0-668b-4496-8c32-746d6775b2f9/lists/9d10764c-dc2e-4fca-8991-653d26ad0096/items/delta?$filter=contentType%2fname+eq+%27Site+Page%27&token=NDslMjM0OyUyMzE7Mzs5ZDEwNzY0Yy1kYzJlLTRmY2EtODk5MS02NTNkMjZhZDAwOTY7NjM4NDIyMzk5Mzg0OTcwMDAwOzU0MTcwODEzNDslMjM7JTIzOyUyMzA7JTIz&",
  "method": "GET",
  "status": 200,
  "header": {
    "Cache-Control": [
      "no-store, no-cache"
    ],
    "Client-Request-Id": [
      "2a3891c1-98c6-444e-88e9-252cbd28459c"
    ],
    "Content-Type": [
      "application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;odata.streaming=true;IEEE754Compatible=false;charset=utf-8"
    ],
    "Date": [
      "Tue, 30 Jan 2024 19:34:06 GMT"
    ],
    "Odata-Version": [
      "4.0"
    ],
    "Request-Id": [
      "bf6fd62a-8b35-4ec4-b5e2-196084867542"
    ],
    "Strict-Transport-Security": [
      "max-age=31536000"
    ],
    "Vary": [
      "Accept-Encoding"
    ],
    "X-Ms-Ags-Diagnostic": [
      "{\"ServerInfo\":{\"DataCenter\":\"Canada East\",\"Slice\":\"E\",\"Ring\":\"2\",\"ScaleUnit\":\"001\",\"RoleInstance\":\"QB1PEPF00001E8A\"}}"
    ]
  }
  "body": {
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#Collection(listItem)",
    "@odata.deltaLink": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/bartek.sharepoint.com,43190b08-6a2a-4b9e-be35-d16751aab8da,56c688c0-668b-4496-8c32-746d6775b2f9/lists/9d10764c-dc2e-4fca-8991-653d26ad0096/items/delta?$filter=contentType%2fname+eq+%27Site+Page%27&token=NDslMjM0OyUyMzE7Mzs5ZDEwNzY0Yy1kYzJlLTRmY2EtODk5MS02NTNkMjZhZDAwOTY7NjM4NDIyNDAwNDczMzAwMDAwOzU0MTcwODg0MTslMjM7JTIzOyUyMzA7JTIz&=",
    "value": []
  }
}
```

I'm not sure how to proceed. There are no further change notifications and the only way I can remove this page from my local data set is if I were to query it directly and sweep it away (using a separate, custom mechanism)

The MS Graph API documentation suggests I should receive this list item like I would a drive Item, where a `deleted` facet is present (as per [listitem: delta](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/listitem-delta?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http))

When I remove a drive item, I can observe the expected behaviour: A change notification is received for the driveId, and upon querying the drive via its Delta API, I get the modified drive item with the deleted facet. The same experience does not exist for site pages.

Am I missing anything in particular or is this a known issue?

Comment: See: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Trigger-email-notification-based-on-deleted-item/m-p/435976#M51185